# Dynamic xml to Java object?

Tags: java, xml

My application returns dynamic XML and I want to create a Java object from that XML. How to do that? Its like creation off dynamic Java class from dynamic XML. Any example will help.

Comment: Why do you need a Class and not a DOM object?

Comment: In addition to the suggested DOM you could also use **groovy** to read your XML which simplifies XML-treatment a lot! (If you have used it once you ask yourself how you have done it before).

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just create a very generic Java class `MyObject` which contains a list of class `MyAttribute` which has values, that way you don't have to know any structure up ahead.

Then again, isn't a DOM enough for you? Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html. What exactly is your use case that you really need actual Java classes for each XML object? That's not a common way to approach problems like these.

Comment: I want a java object which contains all the attributes and values of xml....need to pass to another application

Answer (score 0):

If the XML data is defined in a schema you can create JAX-B classes using xjc provided by your SDK. Once you have the JAX-B classes it's a piece of cake marshalling and unmarshalling XML data over streams.

[http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_3_1-Unmarshalling-and-Using-the-Data.html#Unmarshalling and Using the Data](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_3_1-Unmarshalling-and-Using-the-Data.html#Unmarshalling%20and%20Using%20the%20Data)

Bas van den Broek: Representing XML elements in Java classes might be more common than you think. It all depends on what you need the data for.

Comment: If the xml is not defined then you might be better of with Broeks suggestion.

Comment: Yeah. That's the problem xml schema is not defined. always be getting dynamic xml.